# Display git branch as website

Tags: git

I am an intern at a semi-big company and we are starting to use git. Everything is set up at the moment, only one thing is missing and that is a way to track progress of the projects in a client friendly way.

Ideally we want a website to display the git repo in it's current state. So let's say `dev.website.com` shows the master branch, `login.dev.website.com` shows the branch "login" and so on.

So the idea is not to view the git itself, but the actual website in state of a particular branch. This is a way to check how development is going for non-developers so they can actually *see* the changes. Also, if possible a standalone solution, so not really a complete hosting service.

Comment: Have you checked out Gitlab or Gitblit?

Comment: @user1615903 I looked around on their websites for a bit, seems it is a hosting solution, I'll edit the main post with a bit more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could try [`git instaweb`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-instaweb.html)

```
NAME
       git-instaweb - Instantly browse your working repository in gitweb

DESCRIPTION
       A simple script to set up gitweb and a web server for browsing the
       local repository.
```

[**Example**](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/13/visualizing-your-repo.html)

```
git instaweb --httpd webrick
```

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks for the suggestions but I got it to work. We use Beanstalk as a repository host and guess what, it has deployment built in! Haha didn't even realize this.

Thanks for the effort though, appreciate it.